# PHP - Store value from simplexml_load_file in database

Tags: php, mysql, serialization

I am grabbing an external xml file and converting it into an array with simplexml_load_file in php. My question is, what would be the best way to store that information in a mysql database for processing later? I tried serializing it but I believe you cant do that? When I do I get node no longer valid error or something similiar. Any suggestions/help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you got an XML file, why not store that XML and process it later altogether?

Comment: If I get the xml file into a string and store that into the db, would you recommend I serialize it?

Comment: Serialization is only to write an object or other datatype into a string. So if you got a string, you don't need to serialize it. You could parse the whole XML and store the normalized values into separate tables, but if your goal is just to store the XML for later processing, all you need to do is put that XML string into your database.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize it with [`serialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php), and then unserialize with [`unserialize()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php). However, you are often better [normalising your data](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) into columns/tables/etc so you can use the power of the database to query the data.

Comment: I tried serialize but when I go to unserialize it I get a bunch of errors like so: Warning: unserialize(): Node no longer exists

Answer (score 0):

you could store the raw xml string into a TEXT field, maybe using mysql's compress() function to save space.

But i recommend Alex's answer, normalise your data into proper columns/tables in the database.

```
<itemList>
    <item>
        <name>test</name>
        <value>42</name>
    </item>
    ... etc
</itemList>
```

Table: ItemList

```
|id|name|value|
|1 |test|42   |
|2 |etc | ... |
```

Comment: Im grabbing xml feeds from an api, this is the main reason why I want to just dump the whole file/string into a table so I can do the processing at another time. So when Im ready to process I will then be able to normalize the fields in the xml data.